# MYSQL: How to append Null value using GROUP_CONCAT and Separator using groupby?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

How to display Null using Group Concat and Separator

```
select sr.aID,
 GROUP_CONCAT(p.GENDER SEPARATOR ',') as Gender,
 GROUP_CONCAT(sr.FANS SEPARATOR ',') as FA,
from RELATION sr, Person p where RELATION _TYPE = 'FATHER'
and  sr.bID= p.ID group by sr.subjektA_ID;
```

It returns following value for FA

```
1 | MALE, FEMALE | YES, NO
2 | FEMALE, MALE | NO, YES
3 | FEMALE, MALE | YES
4 | FEMALE, MALE | NO
```

I want it to display Null value i.e

```
3 | FEMALE, MALE | YES, NULL
4 | FEMALE, MALE | NULL, NO
```

How to achieve same using GROUP Concat and Separator along together

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing those `NULL` values with the string literal `'NULL'`:

```
SELECT
    sr.aID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.GENDER) AS Gender,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(sr.FANS, 'NULL')) AS FA
FROM RELATION sr
INNER JOIN Person p
    ON sr.bID = p.ID
WHERE
    RELATION _TYPE = 'FATHER'
GROUP BY
    sr.aID;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT`, like most of the aggregate functions, ignore `NULL` values.  But for presentation purposes, you only want to see the string `'NULL'`, so the above suggestion should work.

Note I also replaced your old style joins with explicit joins.  Also, you should select the same column which you used to aggregate.

Comment: It is working. Let me test and will mark it as answer. Saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sr.aID,
 GROUP_CONCAT( IFNULL(p.GENDER, 'NULL') ) as Gender,
 GROUP_CONCAT( IFNULL(sr.FANS, 'NULL') ) as FA,
from RELATION sr, Person p where RELATION _TYPE = 'FATHER'
and  sr.bID= p.ID group by sr.subjektA_ID;
```

Annotations: GROUP_CONCAT by default separates the fields by "," so, if you like you can omit it, IFNULL (column, 'default_text'), this replaces all the null values ​​with one that you choose by default.